# i need Help (start httpd) On Centos 7

Tags: apache, centos7

[image: SS Status]

output
systemctl status httpd.service -l

[06:58] [server1.mydomain.com ~] # systemctl status httpd.service -l

● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server

Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)

Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-04-25 06:58:33 UTC; 11min ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)

Process: 9018 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Process: 9017 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Main PID: 9017 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 25 06:58:33 server1.mydomain.com systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hnjd.png): Starting The Apache HTTP Server...

Apr 25 06:58:33 server1.mydomain.com httpd[9017]: httpd: Syntax error on line 353 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/suphp.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_suphp.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_suphp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Apr 25 06:58:33 server1.mydomain.com systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hnjd.png): httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Apr 25 06:58:33 server1.mydomain.com kill[9018]: kill: cannot find process ""

Apr 25 06:58:33 server1.mydomain.com systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hnjd.png): httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1

Apr 25 06:58:33 server1.mydomain.com systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hnjd.png): Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.

Apr 25 06:58:33 server1.mydomain.com systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hnjd.png): Unit httpd.service entered failed state.

Apr 25 06:58:33 server1.mydomain.com systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hnjd.png): httpd.service failed.

Comment: Please note that [CODE][/CODE] will not work. Use ```  your code ```

Comment: There is a syntax error in the mentioned document. In line 353. Go to /etc/httpd/conf/http...tory. and check

Comment: Try `systemctl status httpd.service -l`, and give me the output of the full document name.

Comment: The requested command was executed, and the question was modified
Thank you, sir, for helping me

Comment: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_suphp.so doesn't exist. So the error. I am not sure if you have installed suphp properly. do you want to use suPHP?

Comment: Yes I want use suphp .

I followed these steps when installing  :  https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-suphp-on-centos-7/

Comment: Sure you didn't miss `make install`?